# Updating or Creating Shape Data in Visio with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visio

I'm working on a project to create a Visio diagram via PowerShell, and I need to update an existing Shape Data (`Prop.Row_1` — `Prop.Row_3`) for shapes from a stencil.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This simple code works with shape which selected in MS Visio active window

```
$visio = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Visio.Application')
$visio.Visible = $true
$doc = $visio.ActiveDocument
$shape = $visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
$shape.CellsU('FillForegnd').FormulaU = '3'
$shape.CellsU('Prop.Row_1').FormulaU = """New value1"""
$shape.CellsU('Prop.Row_2').FormulaU = """New value2"""
$shape.CellsU('Prop.Row_3').FormulaU = """New value3"""
```

I get this result at my side…
[image]

---

> I get "Unexpected end of file" on the last line.

**UPD** Shape based on master-shape named **PC** have not `Prop.Row_1` - `Prop.Row_3` cells by default!
[image: ShapeData Cells]

Comment: Thanks!  But when i try using the below script I get "Unexpected end of file" on the last line.
`$application = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$application.visible = $true
$documents = $application.Documents
$document = $documents.Add("Basic Network Diagram.vst")
$pages = $application.ActiveDocument.Pages
$page = $pages.Item(1)

$ComputerStencil = $application.Documents.Add("Computers and Monitors.vss")

$pc = $ComputerStencil.Masters.Item("PC")
$shape1 = $page.Drop($pc, 2.2, 6.8)
$shape1.Text = "Some text...."
$shape1.CellsU("Prop.Row_1").FormulaU = "Dynamic Value"`

Comment: Because **$shape1** have not `Prop.Row_1` property! I updated my answer (add picture)…